# Diff between timestamp object to timedelta object

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, timedelta

s = '2022-07-12 20:30:37' (timestamp)
e = '0 days 00:06:31' (timedelta)

diff = e-s

desired result in datetme format

e= dt.datetime.strptime(str(e), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') is not working
Please help. Much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I assume this is Python? Could you please provide a [mre] that shows your problem? At the moment, it is unclear to me. Subtracting timedelta objects from datetime objects works fine.

Comment: In example, s is a timestamp object. e is a timedelta object. I've tried to format e to datetime object e= dt.datetime.strptime(str(e), '%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:%S'). It is not working

Answer (score 0):

subtracting durations from datetimes is pretty straight-forward, ex:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

s = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-07-12 20:30:37') # s: datetime object

e = timedelta(minutes=6, seconds=31) # e: timedelta object

print(s)
# 2022-07-12 20:30:37

print(s-e)
# 2022-07-12 20:24:06
```

Note that you only can subtract a duration from a datetime, not the other way 'round (would make no sense).